# Move navigation to center

Tags: html, css

Working on a html/css page, and found a cool navigation bar which I downloaded and edited. But having the issue to put the navigation in the center of the header. Here is how it looks now:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/20viph17tc36iwb/header.png
```

index.html

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" /> Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/temperatur.png" /> Måling</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/sol.png" /> Dagvakt</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/kveld.png" /> Kveldsvakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/vaske.png" /> Kontroll CM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/søk.png" /> Søk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/top2.png" /> Statistikk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/top3.png" /> Rapport</a></li>
</ul>
```

menu.css

```
ul#nav {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;
    font-size:0;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 0;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c4c4c4); /* FF 3.6+ */  
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c4c4c4); /* IE10 */  
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f5f5f5), color-stop(100%, #c4c4c4)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c4c4c4); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c4c4c4); /* Opera 11.10 */  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#c4c4c4'); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#c4c4c4')"; /* IE8+ */  
    background: linear-gradient(#F2F2F2, f5f5f5); /* the standard - Farge */ 
}
ul#nav,ul#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
}
ul#nav,ul#nav .subs {
    background-color:#444;
    border:0px solid #454545; /* Border */

    border-radius:9px;
    -moz-border-radius:9px;
    -webkit-border-radius:9px;
}
ul#nav .subs {
    background-color:#fff;
    border:2px solid #222;
    display:none;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    padding:0 6px 6px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width:300px;

    border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
}
ul#nav li:hover>* {
    display:block;
}
ul#nav li:hover {
    position:relative;
}
ul#nav ul .subs {
    left:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
ul#nav ul {
    padding:0 5px 5px;
}
ul#nav .col {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
ul#nav li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-size:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
ul#nav>li,ul#nav li {
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
}
ul#nav ul>li {
    margin:5px 0 0;
}
ul#nav a:active,ul#nav a:focus {
    outline-style:none;
}
ul#nav a {
    border-style:none;
    border-width:0;
    color:#181818;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px 18px;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:#fff 0 1px 1px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
ul#nav ul li {
    float:none;
    margin:6px 0 0;
}
ul#nav ul a {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-color:#efefef;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0 0 1px;
    color:#000;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:4px;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:#fff 0 0 0;

    border-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
}
ul#nav li:hover>a {
    border-style:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:#181818 0 1px 1px;
}
ul#nav img {
    border:none;
    margin-right:8px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
ul#nav span {
    background-position:right center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    padding-right:0;
}

ul#nav ul li:hover>a {
    border-color:#444;
    border-style:solid;
    color:#444;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:#fff 0 0 0;
}
ul#nav > li >a {
    background-color:transpa;
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;

    border-radius:11px;
    -moz-border-radius:11px;
    -webkit-border-radius:11px;
}
ul#nav > li:hover > a {
    background-color: #009900;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

design.css

```
#logo { 
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    right: 0 px;
    top: 0px;
}

.header {
    height: 95px;
    background:#F2F2F2;
    border:2px solid #CCC;
    width:1370px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: JSfiddle please. Are you trying to just center the whole menu or do you want the list items to center as well? It's actually two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit more than that.

You have to pre-define the width on your body for your element (nav in this case) to actually adopt a margin.

make sure you have these before you apply the margin

```
html {
   width: 100%;
}
body {
   width: 1200px; /* change this to whatever width you are working with */
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you don't do this, your margin:0 auto on your nav will center it to the left giving the appearance that it didn't work.

EDIT

You have to spend some time creating some basic htmls and learn the fundamentals of website architecture. I appreciate your passion, I was the same way when I started years ago when HTML was simpler, but trust me man, web development has gotten a lot of muscle over the last 10 years. Start from the bottom as move up as you start dominating the concepts.

Here is the JSFiddle for your working solution.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7h3wN/)

Comment: My header is now stuck to buttom.

Comment: Do you have this site in a domain I can inspect? perhaps put all the relevant code in a jsfiddle and let us know. The only thing I can think that will send it to the bottom would be if you didn't give it a height:auto to your body, and that is a guess.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/8hYed/1 As you can see the header is in the buttom which I dont understand why. I am trying to make it look like this: dropbox.com/s/m2ijroj58vey2rf/target.png I also tried to make the witdh to look normal for the screen, so you should not be able to scroll horizontal.

Comment: I'm going to post the jfiddle as an edit to my answer above

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking the time. I will now study the code to see what i missed.

Comment: Good. Like I said, I appreciate the passion. As long as you study my code and learn. Try not to rely on people to code for you. If someone codes something for you, make sure you learn what he did. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thanks! I've worked with bootstrap earlier:   http://student.cs.hioa.no/~s180368/gruppeside/index.html?    The results speaks for it self. It was pretty difficult to make it mobile friendly so I gave up.

Comment: Really. I could help. Bootstrap is 90% of my job....btw, Are you Norwegian? Me and my wife are planning to move to the are or Norway, Sweden, Denmark, Switzerland, etc..

Comment: Good to hear. Yes I am from Norway. Here is the link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6LsG7/    The problem is that I dont want the header or footer to be sticky. The next problem I had was to make it mobile friendly. :/ I noticed that the menu is not a part of the header in jsfiddle.

Comment: This is a separate question alltogether. Stackoverflow may penalize you for mixing questions. They want someone else that may have this same issue to be able to search for it too. Make a separate question and send me the address here so I can track it there. I have your solution I think

Comment: Thanks! Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229305/twitter-bootstrap-not-being-mobile-friendly

Comment: Another question: http://jsfiddle.net/85tU2/

I am thinking to make the name as a variable to show who is logged in but the problem is that the log out buttom goes out of the header when the name is short as Petter, but stays inside when the name is long as Petter Hansen. Is it a solution to make the buttom stay at same position independent of the name size?

Comment: I amde a couple of adjustments to your fiddle to get the margins right. If youa re versed in dynamic coding, which I assume you are since you mentioned variables. Then you will have to use some JS to accomplish what you need. I'm not going to rule out that it can be done with Pure CSS, I just havent got the time today to spend on this. But take a look at this Fiddle I made for another pst. It may be able to help you out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FeRV/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by putting the name in a label. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the property `margin`.

```
ul {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

`auto` means it will be centered is set on both sides.

Comment: Which will center the menu but probably not the list items within it.

Comment: the list items should also centre if given position:absolute I think...

Comment: @celem that not a good idea. It would make more sense to use `display:inline-block` on the `li` and `text-align:center` on the `ul`. It's a common technique.

Comment: Still not working, I added the navigation bar into a container got it centered but not the grey background was gone.. Here are the files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fodg80vfdpir65h/uaKZ0KNvRE

Comment: The target is to make it look like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2ijroj58vey2rf/target.png

Comment: We need a JSFiddle as has been mentioned.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8hYed/1/

As you can see the header is in the buttom which I dont understand why. I am trying to make it look like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2ijroj58vey2rf/target.png

I also tried to make the witdh to look normal for the screen, so you should not be able to scroll horizontal.

Comment: Here is the full screen:http://jsfiddle.net/8hYed/1/embedded/result/

Comment: the header at the bottom should be at the top? You have put this outisde and after the body which is 1000px high...

Answer (score 1):

Just add margin:0 auto; and a fixed width and you got it

```
ul#nav {
display:block;
float:left;
font-family:Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;
font-size:0;
padding:5px 5px 5px 0;
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;

background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c4c4c4); /* FF 3.6+ */  
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c4c4c4); /* IE10 */  
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f5f5f5), color-stop(100%, #c4c4c4)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */  
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c4c4c4); /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c4c4c4); /* Opera 11.10 */  
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#c4c4c4'); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#c4c4c4')"; /* IE8+ */  
background: linear-gradient(#F2F2F2, f5f5f5); /* the standard - Farge */ 
}
```

Comment: `margin:auto` only works when an element has a defined width or `max-width`

Comment: sorry I forgot that, you're right :D .. edited it